# How can i get tag without />?

Tags: tags, html, html5

I see that wordpress make tag meta, link, style, img, ecc.ecc. like theese:
`<img />
<meta />
<link />
<style />`

with the `/>` at the end of the tag.

How can i get tags like thees?
`<img>
<meta>
<link>
<style>`

without `/`

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: That `/` is valid-- optional but valid. "Fixing" that is both unnecessary and wasteful given the overhead you will add to the site to do so. As @Howdy_McGee says below " the overhead and amount of things that could go wrong outweighs whatever OP is trying to achieve"

Answer (score 1):

Capture all the wp_head content

```
add_action( 'wp_head', function(){
    ob_start();
}, 0);
```

Replace endings and output results

```
add_action( 'wp_head', function(){
    $head = ob_get_clean();
    echo str_replace('/>', '>', $head);
}, 99999);
```

Comment: While this *would* work I feel like the overhead and amount of things that could go wrong outweighs whatever OP is trying to achieve.

Comment: I honestly don't think removing `/` makes much sense but this is an option. Perf wise it's pretty stupid, you're correct. The other problem is that maybe there is a better hook for WP but what about plugins? Everyone outputs tags differently so this is the one option to rule them all.

Comment: @jgraup Original Poster.